# Run a exe file through a power shell script

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to run a power shell script which can run a exe file and following are my requirements.
I have that exe file in a remote server location(//ES-WEBSRV01/DBMigration)  which is shared to my local machine. Also I want to run that ps file through a cmd.exe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply call it like any other program:

```
\\ES-WEBSRV01\DBMigration\something.exe
```

or, if it contains spaces somewhere along the path:

```
& "\\ES-WEBSRV01\DBMigration\some thing.exe"
```

I have no clue what you mean by *»Also I want to run that ps file through a cmd.exe.«*, though. If you mean that you need a batch file and want to run the PowerShell script from there, then:

```
powershell -file myscript.ps1
```